# RPM: loading bash script in %pre scriptlet

Tags: bash, rpm, rpm-spec

I've put some common utility scripts into `common.sh`, which I want to use in my RPM specfile during `%pre`. `common.sh` is located in the root of the RPM package.

What I was planning to do is simply call something like `source common.sh`, but how can I access `common.sh` from the RPM during `%pre`?

Comment: If `common.sh` is *inside* the rpm itself I don't believe you can (not reliably at least). The best you could probably do is include `common.sh` as an rpm macro at build time to have it available for `%pre` usage.

Comment: @EtanReisner Do you know any good resources about RPM macros?

Comment: Slightly older but still largely accurate/useful: http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Macros

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks! Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341189/bash-returning-values-from-included-rpm-macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this using [RPM macros](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Macros#UsingaMacro), the following way:

Before doing `rpmbuild` I have put `common.spec` into the `SPECS` folder.

**common.spec**

```sh
%define mymacro() (echo -n "My arg is %1 " ; sleep %1 ; echo done.)
```

I've added `%include SPECS/common.spec` as the first line of my actual spec file.

**Usage example**

```
%pre
%mymacro 5
```

> My arg is 5 done.

**Multi-line macros**

Pretty fragile syntactically imo, but you can put line breaks into your macros using `\`. That will tell the RPM builder that it should continue parsing the macro. Given the previous macro as an example:

```
%define mymacro() (echo -n "My arg is %1 " ; \
sleep %1 ; \
echo done.)
```

This way the code will be still parsed back into a single line, hence the `;` on the first and second line.