# RPM: returning values from included RPM macro

Tags: bash, rpm, rpm-spec

This is a follow-up question to [RPM: loading bash script in %pre scriptlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321890/rpm-loading-bash-script-in-pre-scriptlet).

I am trying to define some utility functions as macros, so later I can `%include` them when building other RPM packages too. Let's say I want to have a function `testfunc()` which I want use to check if something is present on the target system. If the condition is unmet, I want to break the execution of my RPM `%pre` scriptlet.

Things I've tried:

**Defining a bash function in the macro**

*common.spec*

```
%define importfunction() (testfunc() { echo "Cancelling installation!" ; exit 1 ; })
```

*package.spec*

```
%include SPECS/common.spec

...

%pre
%importfunction

testfunc
```

*RPM install output*

> testfunc: command not found

**Exiting directly from macro**

*common.spec*

```
%define testfunc() (echo "Cancelling installation!" ; exit 1)
```

*package.spec*

```
%include SPECS/common.spec

...

%pre
%testfunc

echo "Installation still running :("
```

*RPM install output*

> Cancelling installation!
>
> Installation still running :(

The problem is that the `%pre` scriptlet is not exiting in this case.

**Questions**

- How can I break the execution of `%pre` from my macro?
- Is it possible to return a value from the macro and store them in a variable during `%pre`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop wrapping the macro body in `()`.

That's spawning a sub-shell and preventing the function from being seen in the first case and preventing the `exit` from exiting the `%pre` scriptlet itself in the second case.